# Не проходит 17 тест на acmp

Tags: c++, графы

[Сама задача](http://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=2&id_section=32&id_topic=53&id_problem=1035)

Вкратце, у вас есть количество пунктов, начальный пункт, конечный пункт  и количество ребер считываем в этом порядке. Чтобы перейти из одного пункта в другой необходимо чтобы текущее время было меньше или равно времени пункта отправления. Поскольку у нас есть машина времени, время конечного пункта может быть меньше начального. Время есть абсолютное значение и оно не превышает по модулю 10 в степени девятой.
         `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
          using namespace std;const int sz = 1010;
        const int inf = 1e9;
         #define ll long long
         int main(){
        int n,m,a,b;
    cin>>n>>a>>b>>m;
    vector < vector <long long int> > e(m, vector<long long int>(4));`

```
vector<long long int> d(sz, inf);

for (int i = 0; i <m; ++i){
    cin >> e[i][0] >> e[i][1] >>e[i][2]>>e[i][3];
}

d[a] = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<m; ++j)
        if (e[j][1]>=d[e[j][0]]){

            d[e[j][2]] = min(d[e[j][2]],e[j][3]);   
   }

cout<<d[b];

return 0;
}
```

это сам код. В общем, решение - небольшое изменение алгоритма Форда, а именно вместо длин ребер считаем время и наименьшее время текущего пункта(пункта отправления) должно быть меньше нового времени пункта отправления

Comment: Все условия стоило бы скопировать сюда и подробно рассказать о своей проблеме. Код читать откровенно больно, неужто буквы платные?

Comment: @free_ze формально да, там есть рейтинг решений, в котором чем меньше исходник тем выше ты в рейтинге сдавших конкретную задачу

Comment: @vegorov, может чем меньше бинарник? Иначе как-то дико звучит. Но все же здесь у нас проверка методом пристального вглядывания, а не автотесты.

Comment: @free_ze я понимаю, я просто рассказываю про acmp.ru и их рейтинги. Там именно чем меньше исходник, и поэтому на каком-то языке (Basic?) там были самые топовые решения. Ну, раньше так было, лет 6-7 назад, щас не знаю

Comment: парни эта задача не входит в рейтинг, я быдлокодер сам по себе, но касательно вопроса есть мысли?)

Comment: @Rikudo я не уверен, но может быть здесь имеется в виду немножко другой граф? в котором каждая вершина - это отметка времени ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой задаче `n` раундов недостаточно для нахождения оптимального пути в общем случае. Одна из причин - возможность перемещаться назад во времени. Можно рассмотреть такой набор входных данных:

```
2 2 2 7
1 10 2 -100
2 -5 1 10
2 -4 2 -5
2 -3 2 -4
2 -2 2 -3
2 -1 2 -2
2 0 2 -1
```

Здесь мы сначала небольшими шажками идём назад в прошлое, находясь в городе 2. Затем, наконец, получаем возможность переместиться в город 1, откуда уже делаем прыжок в далёкое прошлое в город 2, который и даёт нам ответ. Соответственно, нужно учесть случаи, когда число рейсов между городами больше, чем число самих городов. Во внешнем цикле по `i` нужно итерироваться не до `n`, а до максимума из `n` и `m`.

Comment: УАУ! спасибо, работает